# How to get a bash terminal in an IPFS docker container

Tags: docker, ipfs

I am running IPFS with docker. The docker-compose.yml is as follows

```
#version of docker compose
version: '3'
services:
  ipfshost:
    image: ipfs/kubo:latest
    container_name: ipfs
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 4001:4001
      - 4001:4001/udp
      - 8081:8080
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      - ./ipfs_staging:/export
      - ./ipfs_data:/data/ipfs
      - ./config:/data/ipfs/config
volumes:
  ipfs_staging:
    external: true
  ipfs_data:
    external: true
```

Currently the only way I can find to run CLI commands is using `docker exec ipfs ipfs [command]`. It's annoying to have to prepend `docker exec ipfs` to every command, but `docker exec -it ipfs bash` does not load a terminal.

The error is:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

I also tried `docker exec -it ipfs /bin/bash`

The resulting error is:

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown`

Is there a fairly straightforward way to solve this? The errors seem to indicate there is no bash software in the docker container.

Comment: `/bin/sh` perhaps?

Comment: This seems to be more a question about running prepackaged software than programming _per se_.  Why is "get a shell inside a running process" a critical task here; can you instead interact with the program through its network interfaces?